# 'GLFW/glfw3.h' file not found on Mac M1

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, homebrew, glfw, apple-m1

I am using GLFW for a c++ project. I downloaded glfw3 using homebrew and have "/opt/homebrew/include" in the "includePath" field of the c++ configurations json file for vs code. Following the solution provided by this post ([MacOS M1 -> fatal error: 'GLFW/glfw3.h' file not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67373307/macos-m1-fatal-error-glfw-glfw3-h-file-not-found)), I also added the two paths to the .zshrc file, using terminal commands:

```
echo -n 'export CPATH=/opt/homebrew/include' >> ~/.zshrc (I also added export CPPPATH=...)
```

and

```
echo -n 'export LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/homebrew/lib' >> ~/.zshrc
```

, respectively. However, at compilation it still says that "GLFW/glfw3.h" is not found, even though the statement completion feature correctly identified both GLFW folder and glfw3.h file in the member lists. Thanks for your help!

**c_cpp_properties.json**

```
{
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Mac",
            "includePath": [
                "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1",
                "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/clang/12.0.0/include",
                "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include",
                "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include",
                "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks",
                "/opt/homebrew/include",
                "${workspaceFolder}/**"
            ],
            "defines": [],
            "macFrameworkPath": [],
            "cStandard": "c17",
            "cppStandard": "c++17",
            "intelliSenseMode": "macos-clang-arm"
        }
    ],
    "version": 4
}
```

**tasks.json**

```
{
    "tasks": [
        {
            "type": "cppbuild",
            "label": "C/C++: clang++ build active file",
            "command": "/usr/bin/clang++",
            "args": [
                "-g",
                "${file}",
                "-o",
                "${fileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}"
            ],
            "options": {
                "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}"
            },
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$gcc"
            ],
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            },
            "detail": "Task generated by Debugger."
        }
    ],
    "version": "2.0.0"
}
```

**launch.json**

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        
        
        {
            "name": "clang++ - Build and debug active file",
            "type": "cppdbg",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${fileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}",
            "args": [],
            "stopAtEntry": false,
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
            "environment": [],
            "externalConsole": false,
            "MIMode": "lldb",
            "preLaunchTask": "C/C++: clang++ build active file"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: How are you building? Did you verify that `/opt/homebrew/include/GLFW/glfw3.h` exists?

Comment: You mentioned VSCode. Did you modify `tasks.json` and `c_cpp_properties.json`? Or are you using code runner? Or the CMake or Makefile addon?

Comment: Yes. Using this path Finder correctly located glfw3.h

Comment: I am using clang

Comment: If you are using VSCode and building from inside VSCode did you add the path in your `tasks.json` and `c_cpp_properties.json` files? The instructions these files is here: [https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-clang-mac](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-clang-mac)

Comment: You did not add the path in the tasks.json. Related: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52910102/vscode-c-task-json-include-path-and-libraries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52910102/vscode-c-task-json-include-path-and-libraries)

Comment: Got it but where should I put it? Placing it after "${file}" or "${fileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}" in "args" still does not solve the issue.

Comment: Adding "IC:" before the path fixes the issue!

Comment: Thanks man! You are so helpful. But what does the keyword "IC mean?

Comment: It should be  `-I` then then the folder